# ParameterExpression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, delegates, expression-trees

I'm creating a general setter using expression tree and here is my code

```
public Expression<Action<T,string>> GetAction<T>(string fieldName)
{
    ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Target");  
    MemberExpression fieldExpr = Expression.Property(targetExpr, fieldName);    
    ParameterExpression valueExpr = Expression.Parameter(fieldExpr.Type, "value"); 
    UnaryExpression valueCast = (!fieldExpr.Type.IsValueType) 
                              ? Expression.TypeAs(valueExpr, fieldExpr.Type) 
                              : Expression.Convert(valueExpr, fieldExpr.Type);
    BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(fieldExpr, valueCast);    
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, string>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr);
}
```

I don't call `.Compile()` in the above method because I want to examine the expression it builds.

And my object is

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

I call the method like this

```
var lastname = GetAction<Person>("FirstName");
var age = GetAction<Person>("Age");

lastname.Compile()(p, "Solutions");
age.Compile()(p, "10");
```

The reason i pass the age as string is, i will be getting this value from XML.

It is creating Action for `FirstName` without any error whereas for `Age` it blows.

Error happens in this line for `Age`:

```
 return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, string>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr);
```

Error:

> ParameterExpression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.String'

Can I do something with dynamic..?

I'm  hoping someone will have some solution. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just cast the age to an int before passing it to the action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) for type conversion:

```
public static Expression<Action<T, string>> GetAction<T>(string fieldName)
{
    ParameterExpression targetExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Target");
    MemberExpression fieldExpr = Expression.Property(targetExpr, fieldName);
    ParameterExpression valueExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");
    MethodCallExpression convertExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Convert),
        "ChangeType", null, valueExpr, Expression.Constant(fieldExpr.Type));
    UnaryExpression valueCast = Expression.Convert(convertExpr, fieldExpr.Type);
    BinaryExpression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(fieldExpr, valueCast);
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, string>>(assignExpr, targetExpr, valueExpr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following:

You are returning an `Expression<Action<T,string>>`, which basically means that the result will be a `string`. On the other hand, you are passing in "Age" as the name of the field the action should return. `Age` however is of type `int`, not `string`.

You can solve this in at least two ways:

1. Add a second generic parameter to your `GetAction` method that specifies the return type.
2. Add a call to `ToString` on the returned property to the expression.